# Django translation - PO file is missing the msgstr, it is appearing as an empty in PO file

Tags: django, translation, language-translation

Here, we are trying to translate the text, however, the PO file is appearing msgstr as ""

```
#: frontend/languages/management/commands/translate.txt:302
msgid "Available Actions"
msgstr ""

#: frontend/languages/management/commands/translate.txt:1787
msgid "Want to add more data you are responsible for?"
msgstr ""

#: frontend/languages/management/commands/translate.txt:1788
msgid "Warning"
msgstr ""

#: frontend/languages/management/commands/translate.txt:1789
msgid ""
"Warning: A virus was found in your file. Please revise your attachments and "
"try again."
msgstr ""
```

Is there any solution to get the translated msgstr?

Comment: What does "Here, we are trying to translate the text..." mean? Translate the text in the `.po` file (adding translated to text to `msgstr`), compile it to an `.mo` file, and reload the application.

Comment: When the script is generating the PO file - it is missing some of the msgstr...

Comment: Added the sample - msgstr is appearing as empty (""), this is not for every text line, most of the text is having translated msgtr however few translated msgstr are not appearing

Comment: Have you translated those strings?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, the instruction

```
django-admin makemessages --locale=fr
```

does not translate anything.

It only generates the a `.po` file for your application to use

Then it is up to you to enter manually the translations for each detected string to translate (the strings after `msgid`).

For each `msgid`, you manually enter the corresponding translation in the "empty string" which is after `msgstr`:

```
msgid "Available Actions"
msgstr "Actions disponibles"

msgid ""
"Warning: A virus was found in your file. Please revise your attachments and "
"try again."
msgstr "Attention : votre fichier contient un virus. "
"Merci de contrôler et re-essayer avec un fichier non-infecté"
```

As you can see, the strings (including empty strings) after msgid or msgstr will be concatenated, so you can split them as you want

Then, once all translations are provided through `msgstr` strings, you can compile the `.po` file through the following command to make your translations availlable throughout your application:

```
django-admin compilemessages --locale=fr -f
```